# SceneKit display a USDZ object on the screen with SwiftUI

Tags: addition, scenekit, usdz

I have created a carousel with a ScrollView that contains as many buttons as there are .usdz files. In the ResourceButton structure, when you tap on a button, it should:

Check if a .usdz file is already present.
If yes:
-Remove the old one.
-Add the new one.
Otherwise:
-Add the new .usdz file to the scene.

My logic seems correct, and there are no error messages. However, when I tap on a button on the device, nothing appears on the screen. Can anyone see what my error might be? Thank you in advance

```
import scenekit
import swiftui

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isUSDZDisplayed = false
    @State private var sceneKitView = SceneKitView(isUSDZDisplayed: .constant(false)) // Create SceneKitView's instance
    
    var body: some View {

            VStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            SceneKitView(isUSDZDisplayed: $isUSDZDisplayed)
                .frame(height: 300)
            Spacer()
            // Overlay aand buttons
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<resourceFiles.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        ResourceButton(fileName: resourceFiles[index], isUSDZDisplayed:    $isUSDZDisplayed, sceneKitView: sceneKitView)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .padding(.bottom, 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SceneKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isUSDZDisplayed: Bool
       private let sceneView = SCNView()
       
       init(isUSDZDisplayed: Binding<Bool>) {
           self._isUSDZDisplayed = isUSDZDisplayed
       }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        let scnView = SCNView()
        let scene = SCNScene()
            if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "digestiveS", withExtension: "usdz") {
                 let scene = try! SCNScene(url: url, options: nil)
            let scaleFactor: CGFloat = 0.5
        }
                // ... (Create and position your model SCNNode here)
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light?.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
        scene.rootNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) 
    {
        // update if needed
    }
    
    func addUSDZObject(fileName: String)
    {
        if let scene = loadScene(fileName: fileName) 
        {
            sceneView.scene = scene
            isUSDZDisplayed = true
        }
    }
    
    func removeUSDZObject() 
    {
        sceneView.scene = nil
        isUSDZDisplayed = false
    }
    
    private func loadUSDZScene(named modelName: String) -> SCNNode? 
    {
            guard let usdzURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: modelName, withExtension: "usdz") else 
            {
            return nil
            }
            let referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: usdzURL)
            referenceNode?.load()
            return referenceNode
    }
    
    
    private func loadScene(fileName: String) -> SCNScene? 
    {
        if let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "usdz") 
        {
            let scene = try? SCNScene(url: modelURL, options: nil)
            print("DEBUG: button name: \(String(describing: scene))")
            return scene
        }
        return nil
    }
}

struct ResourceButton: View {
    let fileName: String
    @Binding var isUSDZDisplayed: Bool
    let sceneKitView: SceneKitView

     init(fileName: String, isUSDZDisplayed: Binding<Bool>, sceneKitView: SceneKitView) {
         self.fileName = fileName
         self._isUSDZDisplayed = isUSDZDisplayed
         self.sceneKitView = sceneKitView
     }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {

            if isUSDZDisplayed {
                           // remove USDZ from screen
                sceneKitView.removeUSDZObject()
                 // add new USDZ from screen
                sceneKitView.addUSDZObject(fileName: fileName)
                       } else {

                           // add new USDZ from screen
                           sceneKitView.addUSDZObject(fileName: fileName)
                       }
                       // switch USDZ dispalyed state
                       isUSDZDisplayed.toggle()

        }) {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: fileName) ?? UIImage()) // load picture  from filename 
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40) 
                            .padding(2.5)
                            //.background(Color.blue)
                            .aspectRatio(1/1, contentMode: .fit)
                            .cornerRadius(12)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .padding(.trailing, 10)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
    }
}

let resourceFiles = ["digestiveS.usdz", "orcas.usdz", "chair_swan.usdz","cup_saucer_set.usdz", "fender_stratocaster.usdz", "flower_tulip.usdz","FruitCakeSlice.usdz", "gramophone.usdz", "LemonMeringuePie.usdz","PegasusTrail.usdz", "robot_walk_idle.usdz", "Rock.usdz","slide.usdz", "solar_panels.usdz", "teapot.usdz","toy_biplane_idle.usdz", "toy_car.usdz", "toy_drummer_idle.usdz","tv_retro.usdz", "wateringcan.usdz", "AirForce.usdz"]  // usdz fileName

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very possible it's just an issue in the SwiftUI state management. Have you tested if the USDZ files display correctly with UIKit? Also, have you tried using the view hierarchy debugger and then exploring the scene inside the SCNView?